# ABPeoplePicker select and return SELECTED phone number

Tags: iphone

Under

> - (BOOL)peoplePickerNavigationController:(ABPeoplePickerNavigationController *)
>
> peoplePicker 
>         shouldContinueAfterSelectingPerson:(ABRecordRef)person
>
> property:(ABPropertyID)property 
>                                 identifier:(ABMultiValueIdentifier)identifier{}

is it possible to get returned the phone number or somewhat the user has clicked?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 id value = [(id)ABRecordCopyValue(person, property) autorelease];

 if (ABPersonGetTypeOfProperty(property) & kABMultiValueMask)
    {
    CFIndex index = ABMultiValueGetIndexForIdentifier(
                        (ABMultiValueRef)value, identifier);

    value = [(id)ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(
                        (ABMultiValueRef)value, index)
                        autorelease];
    }

 // show results to developer...
 NSString* firstname = ( NSString*)ABRecordCopyValue(
      person, kABPersonFirstNameProperty);
 NSLog(@" ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ firstname is %@",firstname);
 NSLog(@" ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ field clicked on: %@", value);
```